# Help identifying MOSFET manufacturer

Tags: mosfet, identification

I have a MOSFET that I'm trying to identify the manufacturer of. I know it's an IRF520N, but it doesn't behave the same as an IOR IRF520N, so I'd like to find the actual manufacturer's data sheet.

The unknown one is the one on the left.

[image: Image of the MOSFET]

Comment: The logo looks a lot like [Alpha Omega](http://www.aosmd.com/products/mosfets) but think that is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer of the left one is a VBsemi Electronics. Link of the datasheet: https://www.alldatasheet.es/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1223698/VBSEMI/IRF520NPBF.html

Comment: How did you identify it? Do you just know this one?